# Custom Glassfish Security Realm does not work (unable to find LoginModule)

Tags: security, jakarta-ee, glassfish, glassfish-3

I'm trying to get a Custom Security Realm in Glassfish working (i tried 3.0.1 final and 3.1 B33). I read nearly all tutorials about this, but it doesn't not work on my System. I'm getting the error

```
Login failed: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: unable to find LoginModule class: com.company.security.realm.CustomLoginModule
```

when trying to login.

Here is what i did:
I created a little Maven project, which contains the needed Realm class, CustomRealm, and the corresponding LoginModule, CustomLoginModule. 
My pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
  <artifactId>security.realm</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>Custom JDBCRealm</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>security</artifactId>
        <version>3.1-b33</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
      <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
                <optimise>true</optimise>
                <debug>true</debug>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>    
      </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

My Custom Realm class:

```
package com.company.security.realm;

import com.sun.appserv.security.AppservRealm;
import com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.BadRealmException;
import com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.InvalidOperationException;
import com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.NoSuchRealmException;
import com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.NoSuchUserException;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.Vector;

public class CustomRealm extends AppservRealm
{
    Vector<String> groups = new Vector<String>();

    private String jaasCtxName;

    private String startWith;

    @Override
    public void init(Properties properties)
    throws BadRealmException, NoSuchRealmException {
        jaasCtxName = properties.getProperty("jaas-context", "customRealm");
        startWith = properties.getProperty("startWith", "z");
        groups.add("dummy");
    }

    @Override
    public String getAuthType()
    {
        return "Custom Realm";
    }

    public String[] authenticate(String username, char[] password) 
    {
        // if (isValidLogin(username, password))
        return (String[]) groups.toArray();
    }

    @Override
    public Enumeration getGroupNames(String username) 
    throws InvalidOperationException, NoSuchUserException 
    {
        return groups.elements();
    }

    @Override 
    public String getJAASContext()
    {
        return jaasCtxName;
    }

    public String getStartWith()
    {
        return startWith;
    }
}
```

My LoginModule class:

```
package com.company.security.realm;

import com.sun.appserv.security.AppservPasswordLoginModule;
import com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.common.LoginException;
import java.util.Set;
import org.glassfish.security.common.PrincipalImpl;

public class CustomLoginModule extends AppservPasswordLoginModule
{
    @Override
    protected void authenticateUser() throws LoginException
    {
        _logger.info("CustomRealm : authenticateUser for " +  _username);
        final CustomRealm realm = (CustomRealm)_currentRealm;

        if ( (_username == null) || (_username.length() == 0) || !_username.startsWith(realm.getStartWith())) 
            throw new LoginException("Invalid credentials");

        String[] grpList = realm.authenticate(_username, getPasswordChar()); 
        if (grpList == null) { 
            throw new LoginException("User not in groups");
        }

        _logger.info("CustomRealm : authenticateUser for " +  _username);

        Set principals = _subject.getPrincipals();
        principals.add(new PrincipalImpl(_username));

        this.commitUserAuthentication(grpList);

    }

}
```

I compiled this Maven project and copyied the resulting JAR-file to the Glassfish/lib directory. Then i added the Security Realm "customRealm" to my Glassfish with asadmin:

```
asadmin create-auth-realm 
  --classname com.company.security.realm.CustomRealm 
  --property jaas-context=customRealm:startWith=a customRealm
```

I also referenced the LoginModule class for the JAAS context of my Custom Realm, therefore i inserted this into the login.conf of my domain:

```
customRealm {
  com.company.security.realm.CustomLoginModule required;
};
```

Although this LoginModule SHOULD BE on the Glassfish classpath, as it's classfile is packaged in the JAR that i put into the Glassfish/lib-dir, it cannot be found when i try to login. For login, i build a simple JSF-project, which calls the HttpServletRequest-login-method of Servlet 3.0. 
When trying to login i'm getting the following Exception:

```
2010-12-24T14:41:31.613+0100|WARNING|glassfish3.0.1|
javax.enterprise.system.container.web.com.sun.web.security|_ThreadID=25;
_ThreadName=Thread-1;|Web login failed: Login failed: 
javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: unable to find LoginModule class:
com.company.security.realm.CustomLoginModule
```

Anybody got an idea what i can do that Glassfish loads the LoginModule-class?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Got it. Seems like newer Glassfish versions require that the Security Realm and the LoginModule are packaged as an OSGi module, which should then be copied into  `glassfish/modules`.

Therefore i changed my pom.xml to create an OSGi bundle, which contains both the CustomRealm and the CustomLoginModule.

Here it is:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>security.realm</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>bundle</packaging>

    <name>Custom JDBCRealm OSGi</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>security</artifactId>
            <version>3.1-b33</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <optimise>true</optimise>
                    <debug>true</debug>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <instructions>
                        <Export-Package>
                            ${project.groupId}.${project.artifactId};version=${project.version}
                        </Export-Package>
                        <Import-Package>
                            com.sun.appserv.security,
                            org.glassfish.security.common,
                            com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm,
                            com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.common,
                            java.util,
                            javax.security.auth
                        </Import-Package>
                    </instructions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**EDIT**

Found a good additional resource here: 
http://blogs.oracle.com/nithya/entry/modularized_osgi_custom_realms_in
, where the Realm and it's LoginModule is build as a hk2-jar.

Comment: I found it more reliable to deploy the OSGi bundle via `asadmin deploy --type osgi /path/to/CustomRealm.jar` instead of copying the jar into a directory (which seems to change with different 3.1.x releases). Otherwise your post is great and helped me heaps solve the problem.

Comment: After you deploy it how can you add the realm ? I try to add my custom realm to the Security domains but It cannot find files. And I am using the full package name of the class.

Comment: You should ask that in a separate SO-question. However, after the realm is copied like described in the answer and Glassfish is restarted, the realm can be choosen inside the admin interface.

Answer (score 0):

This was driving me crazy, I've finally cracked creating a custom realm in glassfish 3.1, turns out that of course its really easy. The following documentation is the key: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2418/beabo.html ... note that it has changed somewhat from the answers above.