# Custom Realm Problem

Tags: java, glassfish, java-ee-6

I followed some step by step tutorials about how to create and use a Custom Realm in Glassfish.
I have done all the steps correctly, but when I want to use the realm in a web app the following exception is thrown :

SEVERE: com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.common.LoginException: Login failed: Failed file login for p.

where "p" is the username I am supplying.

I read all the Q&As in Stack Overflow and some other places, but I found nothing helpful.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest turning on security debug logging in Glassfish for further details. I once had a similar problem with Weblogic and the server logs were able to provide the missing details to solve it.

Here's [a link to the logging configuration section](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2416/gklmn.html) in the Glassfish administration guide. You did not mention which version you are using, but maybe this helps getting started.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Glassfish V 3.1 build 43.
I found that it is a bug in this version. I also tried build 41 but I got the same result.

in V 3.0 there is no problem and every thing is good.
in V 3.1 custom realms are not usable.

It is so bad for GF community to release an important product like an AS with such a bug.

if I am in fault please inform me.

Comment: You might be wrong - Glassfish 3.1 appears to handle some authentication details differently. Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526674/custom-glassfish-security-realm-does-not-work-unable-to-find-loginmodule