# Login with custom Java EE Realm

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, salt, sha256, jdbcrealm

I've created a Java EE Application with glassfish and netbeans.
I installed the custom flexible jdbc Realm from [here](http://flexiblejdbcrealm.wamblee.org/site/). 
I followed all the instructions and used the properties which are shown below(both to default and server-config)

```
datasource.jndi =    jdbc/e-health
sql.seed   = select salt from users where username = ?
sql.groups = select groupname from groups where username =  ?
sql.password = select password from users where username = ?
password.encoding = BASE64
password.digest = SHA-256
jaas.context = myRealm
```

My first question is where should i create the realm, in default-config or in server-config?

I also created the database(E-Health) with tables: users, groups

```
users: username, password, salt
groups: groupname, username(fk->users.username)
```

The reason that i want to use this realm is that i want to encrypt password with salt and with jdbc realm i don't have this option!

My problem is i cant login.

I use net beans IDE and created the login and loginError pages:

**LOGIN.JSP** :

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Login Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="j_security_check" method="POST">
Username:<input type="text" name="j_username"><br>
Password:<input type="password" name="j_password">
<input type="submit" value="Login">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I've created a user using this code in the servlet:

```
if(userPath.equals("/createUser"))
      {

            String Type = request.getParameter("user_type");

            String Id = request.getParameter("amka");
            String Name = request.getParameter("name");
            String Surname = request.getParameter("surname");
            String Nickname = request.getParameter("nickname");
            String Pass = request.getParameter("password");
            String Email = request.getParameter("e-mail");
            String City = request.getParameter("city");
            String Street = request.getParameter("street");
            String Phone = request.getParameter("phone");
            String At = request.getParameter("at");
            String Spec = request.getParameter("spec");


            //byte[] b_pass = Pass.getBytes("UTF-8");                //Κρυπτογράφηση password
            String salt = null;
            String hash=null;

           if ("doctor".equals(Type))

           {

        //   ID = Integer.parseInt(Id);
               MessageDigest md;
    try {

            Random r = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG"); 
            salt=new BigInteger(130, r).toString(32);  
            md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256"); 
            md.update(salt.getBytes("UTF-8")); 
            byte[] digest = md.digest();
            salt=Base64.encodeBase64String(digest);

            md.update(Pass.concat(salt).getBytes("UTF-8")); 
            digest = md.digest();
            hash=Base64.encodeBase64String(digest); // μετατροπή σε Base64



            } 
              catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Servlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

           currentUser.setPassword(hash);
           currentUser.setUsername(Nickname);
           currentUser.setSalt(salt);
           UsersFacade.create(currentUser);

           currentGroup.setUsername(currentUser);
           currentGroup.setGroupname(Type);
           GroupsFacade.create(currentGroup);

           /*
           currentDoc.setIddoctors(ID);
           currentDoc.setName(Name);
            currentDoc.setSurname(Surname);
            currentDoc.setNickname(Nickname);
            currentDoc.setEmail(Email);
            currentDoc.setCity(City);
            currentDoc.setStreet(Street);
            currentDoc.setPhone(Phone);
            currentDoc.setSpec(Spec);
            DoctorsFacade.create(currentDoc);
             */

          }
```

The groups and roles i have created are doctors,pharms,micros,patients,admins.

I've created the roles in the web.xml and glassfish-web.xml:

**WEB.XML**

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        1
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
<error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/WEB-INF/view/error.jsp</location>
</error-page>
<security-constraint>
    <display-name>AdminOnly</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>admin</web-resource-name>
        <description/>
        <url-pattern>/admin/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>admins</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<security-constraint>
    <display-name>DocOnly</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>doctor1</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/view/doc_index.jsp</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>doctor2</web-resource-name>
        <description/>
        <url-pattern>/view/doctor.jsp</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>doctor3</web-resource-name>
        <description/>
        <url-pattern>/view/history.jsp</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <description/>
        <role-name>doctors</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<security-constraint>
    <display-name>PharmOnly</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>pharm</web-resource-name>
        <description/>
        <url-pattern>/view/pharm.jsp</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <description/>
        <role-name>pharms</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<security-constraint>
    <display-name>MicroOnly</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>micro</web-resource-name>
        <description/>
        <url-pattern>/view/micro.jsp</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <description/>
        <role-name>micros</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<security-constraint>
    <display-name>PatOnly</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>patient</web-resource-name>
        <description/>
        <url-pattern>/view/patient.jsp</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <description/>
        <role-name>patients</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <realm-name>myRealm</realm-name>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/login.jsp</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/loginError.html</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>
<security-role>
    <description/>
    <role-name>admins</role-name>
</security-role>
<security-role>
    <description/>
    <role-name>doctors</role-name>
</security-role>
<security-role>
    <description/>
    <role-name>pharms</role-name>
</security-role>
<security-role>
    <description/>
    <role-name>micros</role-name>
</security-role>
<security-role>
    <description/>
    <role-name>patients</role-name>
</security-role>
<resource-ref>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/e-health</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>
</resource-ref>
</web-app>
```

**GLASSFISH-WEB.XML**

```
<glassfish-web-app error-url="">
<security-role-mapping>
<role-name>doctors</role-name>
<group-name>doctors</group-name>
</security-role-mapping>
<security-role-mapping>
<role-name>micros</role-name>
<group-name>micros</group-name>
</security-role-mapping>
<security-role-mapping>
<role-name>pharms</role-name>
<group-name>pharms</group-name>
</security-role-mapping>
 <security-role-mapping>
<role-name>patients</role-name>
<group-name>patients</group-name>
</security-role-mapping>
<security-role-mapping>
<role-name>admins</role-name>
<group-name>admins</group-name>
</security-role-mapping>
<class-loader delegate="true"/>
<jsp-config>
<property name="keepgenerated" value="true">
  <description>Keep a copy of the generated servlet class' java code.</description>
</property>
</jsp-config>
</glassfish-web-app>
```

For start i've created this annotation in the servlet:

```
@ServletSecurity(
@HttpConstraint(rolesAllowed = {"doctors"}) 
)
```

And here's the credentials:

**Username**:John
**Password(with salt)**:kwkBo2sKjPHPvqFTQReMGS8Cbj8PbAoFxvuk
**Salt**:4b8mHanRWrI9HitaES4s8x5F05WWFz3IN3+Hjp7XtRg=

and

**Username**: John
**Groupname**: doctors

The encrypted password is: **12345**

What have i done wrong?

I put in the form the credentials: John/12345 and error page is shown.

Do i have to decrypt some way the password? Doesn't this work by the realm itself?

Comment: The realm goes in server-config.

Comment: Did you add the Realm to glassfish config as described in the "Configure glassfish with the realm definition" section of this documentation?  http://flexiblejdbcrealm.wamblee.org/site/documentation/snapshot/installation.html

Comment: yes i followed all this steps...

Comment: You have 'myRealm' in your configuration, but the examples use  PhotoXChangeRealm { org.wamblee.glassfish.auth.FlexibleJdbcLoginModule required; }; So your login.conf should use: myRealm { org.wamblee.glassfish.auth.FlexibleJdbcLoginModule required; };

Comment: yes i've done that too...I still haven't be able to understand why i can't login! edit: any other idea?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom Glassfish Security Realm does not work (unable to find LoginModule)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526674/custom-glassfish-security-realm-does-not-work-unable-to-find-loginmodule)